# Why is my Joomla 2.5 plugin not working?

Tags: joomla2.5

I have created and successfully installed a plugin in Joomla 2.5 with the following code

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgCustomFunctions extends JPlugin 
{
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        $article->title = "Something!";
        return true;
    }
}?>
```

My understanding is that this should overwrite the title of every article. That isn't happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is in the class name, it should be

`class plgContentCustomFunctions extends JPlugin`

Otherwise Joomla autoloader won't be able to find it

Offtopic: anyone interested in adding tag synonyms for Joomla, [please give your opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173293/tag-synonyms-for-joomla)

Comment: This naming convention is pretty well hidden in the Joomla documentation and unexplained in the tutorials I found!

Comment: Imho, Joomla's documentation is horrible, I often struggle with it. I can't believe that one of the most popular CMS out there has such a poor documentation for developers

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, make sure that your plugin is properly installed and it's activated.

Your problem is that you are trying to set a property that does not really exist:

`$article->title = "Something!";`

If you do a `var_dump($article);` you will see that the only property passed is 'text'.

So with this

`$article->text = "Something!";`

This is obviously a limitation of the onContentPrepare method.

Maybe you can find an event that triggers when saving the article.

Comment: but that's not correct. `$article->title` exists, I just double checked, and it can be normally overwritten

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I am open for learning more, where did you check for $article->title? :) And howcome I managed with the plugin to change the contents of the article but not the title?

Comment: i opened an existing plugin in joomla 2.5 installation, added `var_dump($article)`, saw `title` property, overwrote it with `$article->title = 'blabla';` and verified output on the frontend. it was for `onContentPrepare` event

Comment: I was also able to dump the variable and ultimately, change the title

Comment: Great. So it was the name of the plugin who was faulty?